# Non-default foreign key relationship

Tags: entity-framework-core

Working in EF-Core 3.1 - trying to configure a foreign-key relation on a simple navigation property.
The primary key in the dependent entity is not an integer and does not have the default "ID" name.

I do not want to use the default integer auto-increment ID columns - I know these work fine but it SHOULD work this way too, it really seems simple enough but I cannot find how it is supposed to work.

Following is a simplified example:

```
    public class Customer
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
        public Language Lang { get; set; }
    }

    public class Language
    {
        public String ISOCode { get; set; }
        public String Name { get; set; }
    }
```

Fluent API configuration:

```
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Language> builder)
    {
        builder.HasKey(c => c.ISOCode);
        builder.Property(c => c.ISOCode).HasMaxLength(5).IsRequired();
        builder.Property(c => c.Name).HasMaxLength(64).IsRequired();
    }
```

No error shows up when adding migrations with that code, and the generated
tables seem to look just fine.
However, queries against above always return empty values for the "Lang" property.
For example, following simple query

```
        dbContext.Customers
                 .Where(x => x.ID == 4701)
                 .Include(x => x.Lang)
                 .FirstOrDefault();
```

turns up the correct customer allright, but the "Lang" property is not populated, it is
always empty. I checked the generated SQL for the above query and it is okay - I can run that query in SQL server and it does turn up the value for "Lang".

But EF Core seems to not find the value when returned by the database.

I know that EF Core configures by convention and my column names and types are not what is expected.

So I tried to configure the foreign key in the fluent API but there seems to be no combination of methods which even compiles. The documentation I found from Microsoft on "Relationships" simply omits this case of the simple reference navigation property. They seem to assume you have to put another property into the dependent entity (Language) pointing back to "Customer", which makes no sense whatsoever to me.

Any examples I found online seem to apply either to EF-Core 5 or EF-Core 2 - they don't work in EF-
Core 3.1.

I should just be able to configure the foreign key property. But I seemingly cannot do that on its own, I have to configure the relationship and add the foreign key onto it - but how?
It should be something like:

```
        builder.HasOne(c => c.ISOCode)
               .WithOne(c => ???)
               .HasForeignKey("ISOCode")
```

Seemingly the WithOne must have some sort of property pointing back to Customer - but would that not be a one-to-one relation, which is not even what I want?

Or is the problem just something entirely different?

Comment: `Language` is not dependent, but principal. Dependent == referencing, Principal == referenced. With the original code there is no need to configure the FK (and the one-to-*many* relationship) - by convention EFC  should have created `LangISOCode` column in `Customer` table and set is as FK referencing `Language` table PK. Could you confirm that?

Comment: Yes, that column is created, and the generated SQL for the mentioned query references the correct columns - as I said that generated SQL query is completely correct but in C# the value does not appear.

Comment: Make sure FK and PK values do *exact* match. EF Core client part is case sensitive, so it might return `null` (unmatched) even though the database correctly joins the two tables, in case keys differ by casing.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it - had nothing to do with the foreign key configuration.

For the record - what Ivan Stoev says in the comment above is completely correct - in this scenario EF Core correctly figures out the relationship and key automatically with no added configuration required.

Turns out my problem was caused by the way I was testing it.

I inserted test data within a NUnit test method, then using the same DataContext instance to query it back. And seemingly that does not work. As soon as I used 2 DataContext instances - one for creating the data, one for making queries, the queries started working properly, returning all values desired.

At this point I have no idea why this is so, if it is a bug etc. But the issue I had is solved.